# d3js: maximum value of legend

Tags: d3.js, legend

Code below for legend works fine, but doesn't display the maximum value at the end of the last rect. The maximum value is gonna be 36 always, so I don't mind hard coding it, but don't know how to do it. `data` is an array of integer values ranging between 0 and 36 and the `data` array is fed into the `eye_data[i].value`. I cannot provide the actual data as it is uploaded from a database and a separate file takes care of uploading the values.

```
//this is just an example of the eye_data format
    var eye_data = [
            { locus: "p1", coordinates: {x: "4", y: "1"}, value:"" },
            { locus: "p2", coordinates: {x: "5", y: "1"}, value:"" },
            { locus: "p3", coordinates: {x: "6", y: "1"}, value:"" },
            { locus: "p4", coordinates: {x: "7", y: "1"}, value:"" }];

      function heat_map_graph() {

              var colorScale = d3.scale.quantile()
                  .domain([0, buckets - 1, d3.max(data, function (d) { return parseInt(d); })])
                  .range(colors);

              var svg = d3.select("#punchcard").append("svg")
                  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                  .append("g")
                  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

              var heatMap = svg.selectAll("g")
                  .data(eye_data)
                  .enter().append("rect")
                  .attr("x", function(d) { return (parseInt(d.coordinates.x) - 1) * gridSize; })
                  .attr("y", function(d) { return (parseInt(d.coordinates.y) - 1) * gridSize; })
                  .attr("cx", 4)
                  .attr("cy", 4)
                  .attr("class", "hour bordered")
                  .attr("width", gridSize)
                  .attr("height", gridSize)
                  .style("fill", colors[0])
              .style("stroke", "black");

              heatMap.transition().duration(1000)
                  .style("fill", function(d) { return colorScale(d.value); });

              heatMap.append("title").text(function(d) { return d.value; });

              var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
                  .data([0].concat(colorScale.quantiles()), function(d) { return d; })
                  .enter().append("g")
                  .attr("class", "legend");

              legend.append("rect")
                .attr("x", function(d, i) { return legendElementWidth * i; })
                .attr("y", height + 30)
                .attr("width", legendElementWidth)
                .attr("height", gridSize / 2)
                .style("fill", function(d, i) { return colors[i]; });

              legend.append("text")
                .attr("class", "mono")
                .text(function(d) { return Math.round(d); })
                .attr("x", function(d, i) { return legendElementWidth * i; })
                .attr("y", height + 30 + gridSize);
          }
```

How can the maximum value be displayed at the end of the last legend rect ??

Any help much appreciated !!

Comment: Code looks ok to me. Maybe the last text element is being cut off?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff No, I checked the elements of the page using the web inspector, the maximum value element does not exist at all. The code displays the value to the right of the legend rectangles, and as there is no rectangle after the last one, the maximum value does not get displayed.

Comment: Could you post a complete example please?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I have edited the code in the question, please have a look, your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Will also need the data...

Comment: You probably want just `.domain()` for this. http://jsfiddle.net/AeJ9u/